# I tried to connect MQTTS with my HTTPS server but it didn't work. It works fine on MQTTX but with PHP it doesn't connect

Tags: php, mqtt, phpmqtt

I tried to connect MQTTS with my HTTPS server but it didn't work. It works fine on MQTTX but with PHP it doesn't connect.

```
<?php 

$server   = 'myServer';
$port     = '8883';
$clientId = 'testing';
$username = 'XXXX';
$password = 'XXXX';
$clean_session = false;

$connectionSettings  = new ConnectionSettings();
$connectionSettings->setUsername($username)
    ->setPassword($password)
    ->setKeepAliveInterval(60)
    ->setLastWillTopic('mytopic')
    ->setLastWillMessage('client disconnect')
    ->setLastWillQualityOfService(1);

$mqtt = new MqttClient($server, $port, $clientId);
$mqtt->connect($connectionSettings, $clean_session);

$mqtt->subscribe('mytopic/respond', function ($topic, $message) use ($mqtt) {
    echo $message;
}, 2);

$mqtt->close();
$mqtt->interrupt();
?>
```

How to connect MQTTS with PHP.

Comment: "I tried [...] but it didn't work" does not tell much. Please see the [help] how you can improve your question, e.g. for troubleshooting you should provide error or diagnostic messages. "It doesn't connect" is similar. There  can be many reasons why a system can not connect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For connecting MQTTS we need to add three additional params into the connectionSettings

```
->setUseTls(true)
->setTlsSelfSignedAllowed(true) // Allow self-signed certificates. Discouraged for production use.
->setTlsVerifyPeer(false)           // Do not require the self-signed certificate to match the host. Discouraged.
```

https://github.com/php-mqtt/client-examples/blob/master/03_connection_settings/02_use_tls_without_client_certificate.php

```
<?php 

$server   = 'myServer';
$port     = '8883';
$clientId = 'testing';
$username = 'XXXX';
$password = 'XXXX';
$clean_session = false;

$connectionSettings = (new ConnectionSettings)
    ->setUsername($username)
    ->setPassword($password)
    ->setKeepAliveInterval(60)
    ->setLastWillTopic('mytopic')
    ->setLastWillMessage('client disconnect')
    ->setUseTls(true)
    ->setTlsSelfSignedAllowed(true) // Allow self-signed certificates. Discouraged for production use.
    ->setTlsVerifyPeer(false)           // Do not require the self-signed certificate to match the host. Discouraged.
    ->setLastWillQualityOfService(1);

$mqtt = new MqttClient($server, $port, $clientId);
$mqtt->connect($connectionSettings, $clean_session);

$mqtt->subscribe('mytopic/respond', function ($topic, $message) use ($mqtt) {
    echo $message;
}, 2);

$mqtt->close();
$mqtt->interrupt();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [source](https://github.com/bluerhinos/phpMQTT/blob/master/phpMQTT.php#L139) code for the phpMQTT library you need to pass a `cafile` in the constructor to enable a SSL/TLS connection.

```
$mqtt = new MqttClient($server, $port, $clientId, $cafile);
```

Where the `cafile` is the path to a CA certificate to validate the broker.

Comment: Need? According to the code the **CA-file is clearly optional**. Please clarify in your answer what you're trying to say.

Comment: You need to pass a ca file to enable an SSL connection, look at the if block I linked to.

Comment: @hakre If you think you can give a better answer then please do, but my reading of the code is that the only way to get a SSL/TLS connection opened is gated by the presence of a `cafile` variable which when taken in the context of the OPs question is obvious, if I'm wrong then provide a better answer.

Comment: Hi hardillb, thanks for your reply. But this returns me "PhpMqtt\Client\Exceptions\ProtocolNotSupportedException: The given protocol version [/etc/emqx/certs/emqx.crt] is not supported. in file /var/www/app/data/vendor/php-mqtt/client/src/MqttClient.php on line 88". Is there any way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

OK, first answer was against the wrong phpMQTT library, trying again.

The correct library is here: https://github.com/php-mqtt/client

From the doc:

> // This flag determines if TLS should be used for the connection. The port which is used to
>
> // connect to the broker must support TLS connections.
>
> ```
> ->setUseTls(false)
> ```

e.g.

```
$connectionSettings->setUsername($username)
    ->setPassword($password)
    ->setKeepAliveInterval(60)
    ->setLastWillTopic('mytopic')
    ->setLastWillMessage('client disconnect')
    ->setUseTls(true)
    ->setLastWillQualityOfService(1);
```